# Github action yml file and mysql

Tags: mysql, github-actions

I'm having issues using mysql as the database for my tests that are running in a Github action. I'm using [this as a guide](https://kirschbaumdevelopment.com/insights/laravel-github-actions).

I'm getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.18.0.2' (using password: NO) (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

here is my yaml file:

```
name: LaravelTest

on:
  push:
    branches: [ test ]

jobs:
  laravel_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: kirschbaumdevelopment/laravel-test-runner:8.1
    services:
      testdb:
        image: mysql:5.7
        env:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
          MYSQL_DATABASE: test
          MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        ports:
          - 33306:3306
        options: --health-cmd="mysqladmin ping" --health-interval=10s --health-timeout=5s --health-retries=3
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: Copy .env
        run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress
      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate
      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Compile assets
        run: npm run dev
      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
  forge_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: laravel_tests
    steps:
      - name: Make Get Request
        uses: satak/webrequest-action@master
        with:
          url: ${{ secrets.MOMENTUM_TEST_DEPLOY_URL }}
          method: GET
```

**UPDATE**

I removed this line from my `phpunit.xml` file:

`<env name="DB_HOST" value="testdb"/>`

and now I'm getting a different error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: "using password: NO", but you set a password for root. Are you not using it in the connection? Probably should use both `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` and `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD` as they both refer to the root password.

Comment: @danblack I get the same error with or without `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD`.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some more googling, I found [this post](https://ovirium.com/blog/how-to-make-mysql-work-in-your-github-actions/) which made me go back and pull out the docker container and try to do it using the mysql service that's already available on ubuntu.

Once I was able to successfully start the service and create a database, I then realized that the steps in my action were copying the .env file, and if it wasn't there, it was copying the .env.example file, which I overlooked, and was getting odd results. Once I realized that it was looking in that file for database connection values, I was able to override them with the `env` option in the yaml file. So, I finally got it working, and this is my working yaml file for anyone that may run into this at some point:

```
name: LaravelTest

on:
  push:
    branches: [ test ]

jobs:
  laravel_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    env:
      DB_CONNECTION: mysql
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_DATABASE: testdb
      DB_USERNAME: root
      DB_PASSWORD: root
    steps:
      - name: Set up MySQL
        run: |
          sudo systemctl start mysql
          mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE testdb;' -uroot -proot
          mysql -e 'SHOW DATABASES;' -uroot -proot
      - uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: Copy .env
        run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress
      - name: Generate key
        run: php artisan key:generate
      - name: Directory Permissions
        run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Compile assets
        run: npm run dev
      - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit
        run: vendor/bin/phpunit
  forge_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    needs: laravel_tests
    steps:
      - name: Make Get Request
        uses: satak/webrequest-action@master
        with:
          url: ${{ secrets.MOMENTUM_TEST_DEPLOY_URL }}
          method: GET
```

Comment: why are you declaring "DB_USERNAME" and "DB_PASSWORD", is it required? please reply.